# Background images / scale

Tags: image, units

I have already spent 2 hours figuring out how to position image correctly...
So here is the problem:

I would like to set background image in such way it fits to the real measure (doing iphone modeling tutorial,)

1. I set scale to metric and centimeters
2. During the process the grid is going crazy (super large etc)
3. I put image and it is has 10m size!
4. I change size of image so it ~fits to my needs
5. Then I just can't align the image properly as it jumps when using offset X or Y option (image does not moves smoothly and precisely)
6. Is there a bug or I am doing something wrong. It looks like image offset function is not scaled proportionally

I tried changing grid size, units etc etc but still nothing. I would appreciate your help. I guess it's a beginner problem:)
Thank You in advance

Comment: It would help if you included a link to the tutorial you were using, plus a copy of your blend file, so we can see exactly where the trouble was - http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Don't use background images, use empties with images instead. They are a much more modern and robust solution, built to replace the older background images system.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I did it with empties as suggested( new stuff for me). I am new to 3D and blender and amazed about its possibilities and community answers here. I think I figured out how to solve the problem with background img.-I think that If I add any object and set grid size at first, then the background image can be moved smoothly, however your solution was better.